# How to get syntax highlighting in Progress 11.6 AppBuilder's section editor and procedure editor

Tags: syntax-highlighting, openedge, progress-4gl

This question is a follow-up of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65522055/how-to-avoid-appbuilder-removing-pieces-of-code):

My situation is the following: I would like to do some development. There exist tools who offer syntax highlighting, but the official tools seem not to, as you can see from those images:

Syntax highlighted excerpt of previous answer:

[image: editor with syntax highlighting]

What do I see when I do this:

[image: my editor does not have syntax highlighting]

According to my colleagues, there was syntax highlighting in the past, but as a result of some upgrade, there wasn't anymore, and they have no idea what happened.

Does anybody know how to get syntax highlighting in Process' release 11.6 AppBuilder and corresponding tools?

For your information, for syntax highlighting purposes, I'm currently using the Notepad++ one, as described in [this URL](https://www.progresstalk.com/threads/user-defined-language-notepad.121480/).

**edit after question about configuration**

Hereby an excerpt of the configuration, as requested:

```
Configuration File:     C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\PROGRESS.CFG

Company Name:   Microsoft

Product Name:   Progress Dev Studio OE
User Limit:     2
Expiration Date:    None
Version Number:     11.6            
Machine Class:      KB
Port Number:    31
```

There are similar entries of the product names "OE Workgroup RDBMS", "Client Networking" and "Translation Manager".

(For security reasons, I've removed any referenced about IDs, like serial numbers, I hope the control numbers are not what you're looking for?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the 32 or 64 bit version of OpenEdge Studio?

Comment: @MikeFechner: I'm not using the OpenEdge Studio, I'm just using the AppBuilder and according tools. The about-box mentions "Release 11.6", ... "Windows 8 (6.2.9200) on x64". (I know it's outdated but I don't work here long enough to ask for an upgrade of the whole development environment)

Comment: OpenEdge Studio is the license that contains the AppBuilder as the developer tool. The alternative (which you do not seem) to have is Progress Developer Studio). Please check the "License Info" tool.

Comment: %DLC%\bin\showcfg.exe - where %DLC% is the installation folder of your OpenEdge product,.

Comment: @MikeFechner: I've updated my question again, showing the configuration you requested. For security reasons, I've decided not to put "personal" information like serial numbers, and for the same reason I've also removed the so-called "control numbers" (I have no idea what those are), I hope those are not what you are looking for?

Comment: Serial number and control codes are needed during installation. It was a good idea _not_ to make them public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - different scenario. You *do* actually have a Progress Developer Studio license (Eclipse based IDE). In that case, Progress is not providing the color-coding in the classic AppBuilder I'm afraid. That was a st...d Product Management decision years ago to save some pennies on 3rd party royalties.

If you're licenses are coming from the OEDK or PSDN subscription, you can install OpenEdge Studio in parallel - as the subscription contains both products. That's the license that provides the color-coding for the AppBuilder.

If you're not using Progress Developer Studio (Eclipse based IDE) now and will not do so in the foreseeable future, you could reach out to Progress Software and apply for a license change.

I'm afraid this is more a commercial issue than a technical issue.

Comment: So the answer on my question "How can I ..." has as an answer "It's impossible." (but there are workarounds). Although I don't like the situation, now I know where I stand. For the time being, I'll keep working with the AppBuilder, session Editor and Notepad++ (the latter for syntax highlighting). It's certainly not ideal but once I have gained some authority over here, I'll push for upgrading to more modern development environments.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax highlighting in the 64 bit AppBuilder (prowin.exe, not prowin32.exe) was introduced in OpenEdge 11.7

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/000042690

If you're using a 64 bit OpenEdge Studio license, the simplest fix would be switching to a 32 bit license - if you can still get that from Progress Software.

Comment: I seem to be using the 32-bit version, as you can see in this excerpt from `tasklist | findstr "prowin"`: `prowin32.exe  ... 13556 Console ... 1 ... 85.436 K`.

Comment: According to the mentioned URL, 32-bit version (which I seem to have) should cover syntax highlighting. Apparently something's going wrong here then.

Comment: Knowing your installed products (license info) becomes more important now.